# Breaking the Nth time a line gets executed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

Is there a way to tell the Visual Studio debugger, "break at this line the Nth time it gets executed, not before" (where N is an integer greater than 1)?
(Just for information, I'm using the C# programming language.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy96wbwd.aspx) MSDN article - How to: Specify a Hit Count.

In short - in the breakpoints window you right click the breakpoint and select `Hit Count`.

Answer (score 1):

You also may try setting up a counter variable and then use a conditional break point and call:

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

under a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you add a conditional breakpoint and use the breakpoint hit count option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290719(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That's an article for Visual Studio 2003.